# How to integrate spring jpa with spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning about spring boot. Can I integrate spring boot with hibernate (spring jpa). Accessing data with MySQL Database? Please help me. I'm using spring boot 2.x.x.

Comment: yes, you can...

Comment: There are lot of tutorial available in the internet. Please check those.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, you can integrate spring boot with spring jpa - hibernate. 
Add the dependencies to the project's pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please edit to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks.

Comment: You still need to *explicity* mention that you are affiliated with the linked site, your recent edit still isn't enough.

Comment: Thank you, very useful information! I am a beginner in Spring Boot

Comment: In here <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>, how to config Spring Boot with MySQL database and JPA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can integrate Spring Boot with Hibernate. You just need to add following dependencies in your spring boot project.

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Hibernate provides implementation of JPA. Basically hibernate is a ORM. 
For the sake of example, start using In memory database with following dependency in your POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! can i add <version>5.2.12.Final</version> in spring boot?

Comment: yes, you can add this as well. It will make it easy for you to manage versions off all the dependencies related to JPA.

Answer (score 0):

To use JPA add the following dependency in your POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```